# Как в аргументах main принять файл

Tags: java

Как принимать в main аргументах файл? На что можно заменить `String[] args`

У меня программа в целом делает так, что открывает файл, читает, закрывает.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s;
        ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Pol\\IdeaProjects\\Task1\\src\\main\\resources\\File.txt"), "CP1251"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Файл не был найден, нужно скорректировать путь");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; (s = br.readLine()) != null; i++) {
        inputs.add(s);
        }
        br.close();
```

Comment: ни на что не надо менять. если изменить сигнатуру метода main, то он перестанет быть точкой входа. но в аргументах этого метода вы получаете массив строк, посему никто не мешает в этом самом массиве передавать путь к файлу либо пути к файлам, если их много

Comment: Получается, что аргументы в методе main меняем по необходимости только тогда, когда работаем с командной строкой?

Comment: @Blacit получается, что аргументы в методе main не меняем, о чём вам написали в первом комментарии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто использовать первый элемент массива:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String path = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : null;
        ...
    }

}
```

Соответственно запуск будет следующим:

```
java Main C:\Users\Pol\IdeaProjects\Task1\src\main\resources\File.txt
```

Рекомендую воспользоваться каким-нибудь готовой библиотекой. Примеры:

- [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)
- [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/)

Можете также ознакомиться со следующими обсуждениями на английском языке:

- [How do I parse command line arguments in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java)